# Extract part of the string to another variable

Tags: php

I have a list of names and jobs saved as `.txt`. 
Ex:

```
John Doe Designer\n 
Another Name AnotherJob.
```

and i have to separate the name and its job. I used `explode("\n")`, to separate the lines.
Here is the thing: I have all the jobs names in an array, how can i extract the name from the string to another variable? So the output would be:

```
$name = "John Doe";
$job = "Designer";
```

Comment: In this list of strings, are the name and job values separated by spaces? How would you know whether it is a person with a name containing one, two, or even no spaces? I think you need to rethink how you are storing that data, look into `csv` format for an easy example.

Comment: It is hard to break until unless your job is a one word only..if luckily it job is a word length then u can explode the string and use `end()` for the job..otherwise it is hard to crack the nut with this existing system

Comment: I can leave the name only using str_replace(array of jobs, "", $string); but i just want to know which job was replaced

Comment: @JoãoRafael Then why don't you just iterate through the array of jobs manually using str_replace rather than use the job array?  By doing this, you would know exactly which job had a match and caused a replacement.

Comment: I just found a solution: strstr($string, $value). It will return the string before or after the match, so i can later use substr to remove it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect as the comments state but for your text this would work.
if you have some one with 1/3 or more parts to there name it would mess up but for your example this will do the trick

```
$text = "John Doe Designer\n Another Name AnotherJob";
$parts = explode("\n", $text);

$persons = array();

foreach($parts as $key => $part){
    $personData = explode(" ", $part);
    $job = str_replace($personData[0]." ".$personData[1], "", $part);
    $persons[] = array(
      "fname" => $personData[0],
      "lname" => $personData[1],
      "job" => $job
    );
}

print_r($persons);
```

Comment: the lines are already separated, i just want to extract the job from the string like it is with str_replace("name of the job", "", $string); but when a match is found i will know which job was replaced

Comment: well then you dont need the first 2 lines if the text is already in lines after that you get an array of people with a auto_increment key that equals an array of first name, last name and there job so long as everything follow the exact rule of
FirstName LastName Job it will work you could also use `"job" => $peronData[2]`

Comment: Why `as $key => $part` instead of just `as $part`?

Comment: Incase any work ever requires it as it is the php core (C++) is still counting them there just not exposed to a php variable so for better reading and to alow alterations based on a key if its needed it's there tiny amount of memory overhead from it saving an int in memory is tiny

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the job names in an array you can do something like this:

```
function getName($line, array $jobs)
{
    foreach ($jobs as $job) {
        if (substr_compare($line, $job, -strlen($job)) == 0) {
            return rtrim(substr($line, 0, -strlen($job)));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$line = 'John Doe Designer';
$name = getName($line, array('Designer'));
```

Based on a given line in your text file, the function will test whether it ends with a particular job; if it does, the name is the part in front of it.